# Clojure/Seesaw HeadlessException

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I am getting a HeadlessException when I try to create a frame in seesaw. Specifically I run

```
(seesaw.core/frame :title "Hello" :on-close :exit)
```

and get

```
HeadlessException   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless (GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
```

My dependencies are

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0"]
             [seesaw "1.4.2"]]
```

I am running ubuntu 12.10 on a virtualbox machine on a windows 7 laptop with no additional screens. I have tried the following but with no luck.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the virtualbox have X11 running? Are you able to run and display other x11 apps?

Comment: I've now installed X11 as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-12-04-lts-x64. I still get the same error. I don't know how to answer the second question. Just to be clear, I'm not trying to display anything remotely, I'm using the virtual machine like I would a local machine and it runs and displays everything as you would expect. Thanks, Alex.

Comment: In order to use standard graphical apps (including swing) under Linux, an X11 windowing server must be running and available to the process. The X host can be the same host as the one running the process or a remote host. Can any apps that use X11 display? The reason I ask is that a headless error indicates to me that the app is not seeing the display context it needs. Is there an x11 enabled variant of the jvm you need to install?

Comment: I looked at this and I'm pretty sure an X11 server was running. Isn't this how all GUI interactions are handled in linux? Or maybe can you give me an example of an app that uses X11 to test with? I couldn't find any info on X11 and JVM compatibility.

Comment: X11 is not the only linux interface. You can use a shell directly from the linux framebuffer (and command line programs). I asked my question because you never mentioned the full bitmap GUI was running. If it is, open an xterm and check the DISPLAY environment variable (it will not always be :0.0). Also, can you run java programs that use swing?

Comment: Coincidentally, after having tried to address this question, I encountered the same bug. In my case ring was trying to use AWT to open a browser window, and `lein ring server-headless` sufficed to eliminate the symptom. I guess the answer is probably to make sure awt is installed and working properly?

Comment: I just noticed I had the package openjdk-7-jre-headless installed - can you check your packages to see if you have a headless jre, and try installing the jre without the -headless extension?